# Two masses attached by a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, frequency

> Suppose there is a system of two masses $M_1$ and $M_2$ connected by a spring with constant $K$ on a frictionless surface. What is the frequency of this system's oscillation?

So I have fixed a coordinate system with the first mass at position $x_1$ and the second at $x_2$ so that if the spring has length $l$ at equilibrium, we have:

$$m_1 x_1'' = k \left([x_2-x_1]-l\right)$$
$$m_2 x_2'' = -k \left([x_2-x_1]-l\right)$$

but I don't know how to solve this to find frequency. Any hints? I suppose I could try to solve this system of differential equations, but I don't really know how.

Comment: In addition to joshphysics answer. You can try to solve the system using Jordan's form, altough it's much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. The derivative is linear, so for any two functions $f$ and $g$ one has $(f+g)'' = f''+g''$.
2. Let $x = x_1 - x_2$, and try to manipulate your equations into one equation for $x$.

Comment: @joshphysics so would that mean that the distance between the two masses follows a oscillatory motion?